# Would it be possible to make extra small class in bootstrap 4 responsive in all small screen devices

Tags: bootstrap-4

Would it be possible to make an extra small class in bootstrap 4 responsive in all small screen sizes? For example when using this like class="col-1".

Here's my code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8">
        <div class="card bg-success border-0 ">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-title">
                    <h1>30 day free trial</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="card-description">
                    <p>Increase your employees' happiness, engagement, and loyalty with a 30 day trial where you can <span>use all of our features for free:</span> </p>
                </div>

                <div class="card-checklist">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                            <span style="font-weight: 600">Weekly automated surveys <span style="color: #fff0ff; font-weight: lighter">– find out if your employees are happy, frustrated, or need support.</span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-11">
                            <span style="font-weight: 600">A safe space for honest feedback <span style="color: #fff0ff; font-weight: lighter">– get to the heart of your employees' needs with anonymous messaging.</span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-11">
                            <span style="font-weight: 600">Employee happiness monitor <span style="color: #fff0ff; font-weight: lighter">– see the current state of your company's health in one actionable dashboard, and take immediate action where needed.</span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want the fa-check to be inline just like this:

[image: inline fa-check right with text description left]

Comment: What do you mean by `all small screen sizes`? mention the breakpoint instead. Bootstrap  4+ does not have `*-xs-*` classes. Use `col-*` instead of `col-xs-*`, for eks, `col-12` instead of `col-xs-12`.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 doesn't include a `*-xs-*` class by default, so if you need to target the minimal size, you'd need to just use the `col-*` without the breakpoint. And then add upon the other breakpoint settings.
For example, if you need 2 columns on `xs` and then 4 columns from `sm` and above, use:
`col-2 col-sm-4`. The `col-2` will apply 2 columns on every size till `sm`, and from there it'll apply 4 columns.